How to handle Neumann conditions in biharmonic weak form?
Consider the weak form of the equation $\Delta^2 u = f$ involving the bi-Laplacian:
$$\int_{\Omega} v\Delta^2 u = \int_{\Omega} vf \rightarrow \int_{\Omega}\Delta v \Delta u +\int_{\partial\Omega} v\partial_n\Delta u - \int_{\partial\Omega} \partial_n v \Delta u = \int_{\Omega} vf.$$
I have the boundary conditions $\partial^2_n u|_{\partial\Omega} = g$ and $\partial^3_nu|_{\partial\Omega} = h$ (I am aware that the Neumann conditions do not provide for a unique solution if there are no additional constraints prescribed). Then supposing that the boundary is piecewise flat (i.e. the mean curvature is zero, and derivatives of the normal are zero) I have (where $\tau$ is the tangent space to $n$):
$$\Delta u = \underbrace{\partial_{nn} u}_{g} + \Delta_{\tau} u, \quad \partial_n \Delta u = \underbrace{\partial_{nnn}u}_{h} + \partial_n\Delta_{\tau}u.$$
This leads to the form:
$$\int_{\Omega} \Delta v \Delta u + \int_{\partial\Omega}v\partial_{n}\Delta_{\tau}u - \int_{\partial\Omega} \partial_n v \Delta_{\tau}u = \int_{\Omega} vf -\int_{\partial\Omega}vh + \int_{\partial\Omega}\partial_n v g.$$
Is my bilinear form now
$$b(v,u) = \int_{\Omega} \Delta v \Delta u + \int_{\partial\Omega}v\partial_{n}\Delta_{\tau}u - \int_{\partial\Omega} \partial_n v \Delta_{\tau}u ?$$
Or maybe is it true that $\int_{\partial\Omega}v\partial_{n}\Delta_{\tau}u - \int_{\partial\Omega} \partial_n v \Delta_{\tau}u  = 0$?
What happens if I have a curved boundary? I have seen the following formula $\Delta u = \partial_n^2 u + (d-1)H\partial_n u + \Delta_{\tau}u$ elsewhere, so I suppose things get quite a bit more complicated. There $\partial_n^2 u$ is to be understood as $n^TD^2(u)n$ and not as $n^T\nabla n^T\nabla u$, $H=\nabla\cdot n$ is the mean curvature, and $d$ is the dimension.

Turns out this is indeed the bilinear form and the boundary term doesn't have to be zero. In 2D one can verify that
$$\int_{\Omega}2\partial_{xy}u\partial_{xy}v - \partial_{xx}u\partial_{yy}v - \partial_{yy}u\partial_{xx}v = \int_{\partial\Omega} -\partial_{\tau\tau}u\partial_n v + \partial_{n\tau}u\partial_{\tau}v = \int_{\partial\Omega} -\partial_{\tau\tau}u\partial_n v + v\partial_{n\tau\tau}u.$$
Then the bilinear form could be written as:
$$\int_{\Omega}\Delta v \Delta u + (1-\sigma)(2\partial_{xy}u\partial_{xy}v - \partial_{xx}u\partial_{vv}-\partial_{yy}u\partial_{xx}v),$$
for $\sigma=0$. The above can also be seen as arising from the potential energy for the thin plate:
$$J(v) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} |\Delta v|^2 + 2(1-\sigma)((\partial_{xy}v)^2 - \partial_{xx}v\partial_{yy}v) - vf.$$
This is discussed for example in "IS THERE MORE THAN ONE DIRICHLET-NEUMANN
ALGORITHM FOR THE BIHARMONIC PROBLEM?.
